# Bind method to another method in php

Tags: php, laravel

This is probably something that anyone knows but me, I don't even know what to search for besides this in the title.

How does laravel etc use method middleware in __construct in way to call it only on  specific methods in that class?

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('auth')->only(['index']);
}

public function index() {
  //Do something as auth..
}

public function show() {
  //Do something without auth..
}
```

I made a class Auth:

```
class Auth
{
  public static function user() {
    //Check is user logged in and redirect if not
  }
}
```

In main Controller class I added method:

```
public function middleware($who) {
  Auth::$who();
}

public function only(array $methods) {
  //Use middleware on using these methods
}
```

Now here is where I am stupid:

When I call lets say:

```
$this->middleware('user');
```

Inside some method it works as expected.

But when I use that in `__constructor` it runs on all methods that I call, how can I check which methods should use that middleware method from constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Quick check to source of laravel and you will get answer.

You can do this magic in laravel controller `$this->middleware('auth')->only(['index']);`
because each controller *should* extend abstract controller provided by laravel.
And abstract controller have method called `middleware`, this method add informations about which middleware should be called to specific method/route.

If you will check middlewars from laravel, you will find another answer, how middlewars check's how can they get and respect this information.

Comment: I did tried before posting  question and still or I dont understand their code or I cant find what I need